# Java & MySQL Real Time Application

Tags: java, mysql, percona

I'm currently developing HMS application, multi network users working together, i want to be able to:

1. When user one update patient record, user2 auto refresh the view.
2. When user editing a patient file, user2 if try edit Java dialog will appear with a message (User already editing this file, you can't commit your changes).

these points is so important for me, so any one can help in this?!

Answer (score 0):

1.) you must create a javascript for your `autorefresh` function.

2.) the table to which it contains patients must a column (*let's say `UserEditing`*) that indicates that someone is editing or not (eg `1` for *someone is modifying* or `0` *when not*). This is usually called `flag`. Every time a user tries to edit patients info, your application must check for the value of this column `UserEditing`. If it retrieves `1` then your application pops a message indicating that someone is editing on the patients.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: your answer is good, but I develop a desktop application using java & mysql database.

Comment: it can be applied on desktop applications too. but for no 1, there are many alternatives for that. one is by creating a thread the value and refreshes the patients for if it has done editing.

Comment: How database can tell the other users to refresh? is there a way when database updated then sending a a refresh request to all other opened client then doing the refresh? since i don't to do refresh all the time, just i need it when changes done if there is any.

Comment: is there an interface between MySQL server & Java?

Comment: you need to add another field in the table (eg. `ForRefresh`). Let's say you have another thread which checks for this value. `ForRefresh` field should be set after someone is editing on the patients profile.

Comment: `sending a a refresh request to all other opened client` requires expensive network bandwidth,much better to use `flags` in the fields.